# Working with a serialized PHP associative array within an array

Tags: php

I have this array and I'd like to access the `itemDescriptors` for use in my template; I'm not familiar with `json_decode` at all but I feel like I need to use it here but I'm not sure how. I've tried looping through with js and php but it only returns 0.

Guidance is much appreciated!

```
$array = Array 
(
  [0] => Array
    (
      [itemId] => 1
      [itemName] => Item 1
      [itemDescriptors] => a:3:{s:5:"color";s:3:"red";s:4:"size";s:2:"12";s:3:"cat";s:5:"shoes"}
    )
)
```

Comment: This is not json, this is serialized value, Use `unserialize` to restore it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is not JSON encoded, but in a [serialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php) form. To access [unserialized](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php) form (as an array), do the following:

```
$itemDescriptors = unserialize($array[0]['itemDescriptors']);
```

Comment: Thank you, I had no idea! Once I'm able to select an answer I'll tick this.